# How to make a long column out of a html table

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to modify a html using JS table but keep failing. I want to take a simple table, slice it into columns and make a long one column table made out of each column of the original table. Here is a basic table:

[image]

For now I succeded only to slice it rowwise:

[image]

But my goal is to make it look like:
Column 1
Data 1
Data 4
Data 7
Column 2
...and so on.
(Vertically)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transform Table</title>
    <style>
        /* Hide the transformed table by default */
        
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            transformTable();
        };
        
        function transformTable() {
            var originalTable = document.getElementById("originalTable");
            var transformedTable = document.getElementById("transformedTable");

            for (var i = 0; i < originalTable.rows.length; i++) {
              var row = originalTable.rows[i];
              for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
                  var cell = row.cells[j];
                  var newRow = transformedTable.insertRow();
                  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();

                  // Clone attributes from original cell to the new cell
                  for (var k = 0; k < cell.attributes.length; k++) {
                      var attr = cell.attributes[k];
                      newCell.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
                  }

                  // Clone nested elements
                  var cellContents = cell.cloneNode(true);
                  // Remove the cloned <td> element and append its children
                  while (cellContents.firstChild) {
                      newCell.appendChild(cellContents.removeChild(cellContents.firstChild));
                  }
              }
          }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Original table visible on normal view -->
    <table id="originalTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="original-cell"><div class="cell-content">Column 1</div></td>
            <td class="original-cell"><div class="cell-content">Column 2</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Column 3</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 1</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 2</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 3</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 4</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 5</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 6</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 7</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 8</div></td>
            <td><div class="cell-content">Data 9</div></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
    </table>

    <!-- Transformed table visible on mobile view -->
    <table id="transformedTable" style="border: 2px solid black">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide at least one example of the HTML that you're trying to reformat, or otherwise alter. Please take a look at the "*[mcve]*" guidance, along with the advice - from [Meta] - on how to compose a Stack Snippet: "*[I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548)*"

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using only CSS:

```css
#transformedTable {
  width: 77px;
  display: table-column;
  height: 287px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#transformedTable td {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#transformedTable td:nth-child(2) {
  top: 93px;
  left: -70px;
}

#transformedTable td:nth-child(3) {
  top: 187px;
  left: -140px;
}

#transformedTable .cell-content {
  width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Transformed table visible on mobile view -->
<table id="transformedTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="original-cell">
      <div class="cell-content">Column 1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="original-cell">
      <div class="cell-content">Column 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Column 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 5</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 7</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 8</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-content">Data 9</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all `td` and take into account the index:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.table-desktop').forEach(table => {
  const output = [];
  table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
    tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td, index) => {
      if(!output[index]) {
        output[index] = `<tr>`;
      }
      output[index] += `<td>${td.innerHTML}</td>`;
    })
  })
  table.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = output.join('');
})
```

```css
.table-desktop td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (width < 768px) {
  .table-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

.table-mobile,
.table-mobile tbody {
  display: block;
}

.table-mobile tr {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-mobile tr:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-mobile td {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}

.table-mobile td:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

@media (width > 767px) {
  .table-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-desktop table">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 4</td>
    <td><b>Data 5</b></td>
    <td>Data 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 7</td>
    <td>Data 8</td>
    <td>Data 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table-mobile table"></table>
```

Comment: The OP wants a vertical column, not a horizontal one.

Comment: @i0rg You are right, sorry. It's I didn't understand the question correctly. But the very essence of rebuilding cells does not change from this. I updated my answer by adding some css.